# Re-indexing SOLR document

Tags: solr, solrj

I have one file named item.csv, which contains around 100 products for now and it is indexed using SOLR.My requirements is if I add more data around 10 to 100 products on daily basis, do I need to re-index the whole document daily,or does SOLR support indexing only those new data?

Can anyone please clarify my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can just add new documents to the index without having to rebuild the whole index.

If you mean appending data to (or updating) an *existing document*, then yes, you have to rebuild that *document*.