# solr indexing and reindexing

Tags: solr, content-indexing

I have the schema with 10 fields. One of the fields is text(content of a file) , rest all the fields are custom metadata. Document doesn't chnages but the metadata changes frequently .
Is there any way to skip the Document(text) while re-indexing. Can I only index only custom metadata? If I skip the Document(text) in re-indexing , does it update the index file by removing the text field from the Index document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update specific field on SOLR index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032813/update-specific-field-on-solr-index)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038920/updating-solr-schema and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474276/re-indexing-solr-document

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there's no way to selectively update specific fields. An update operation performs a complete replace of all document data. Since Solr is open source, it's possible that you could produce your own component for this if really desired.

Comment: +1 you can implement this pretty easily in a custom updatehandler

Comment: @Pascal Dimassimo: I am using DIH with data-config.xml